# Tecnology to make something like Talking Tom and Pou game's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I'm actually doing a small game like Talking Tom and Pou. 
This game is to include in a website developed in asp.net with mvc.

In what language i can make this ? It's possible to make in HTML5 with canvas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do incredible things with JavaScript today. 2d and 3d graphics, sound and input device reading.

E.g. see [JavaScript Graphics](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013044.do) or [WebGL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029205.do) or [WebAudio](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025948.do).